# Start a background process upon successful quickstart in cherrypy

Tags: python, rest, subprocess, cherrypy

I have a REST WebService built on top of cherrypy. The service goes online with the `cherrypy.quickstart()` call.

I want to start a background process with `subprocess.Popen()` right after the service goes online. The `cherrypy.quickstart()` call is blocking. How can I add a callback to start the background process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your background task is simple and isn't CPU-bound I would suggest you to use [`cherrypy.process.plugins.BackgroundTask`](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.process.html#cherrypy.process.plugins.BackgroundTask). It's a thread based solution. Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27489635/2072035) with complete example.

Generally in CherryPy we don't pass callbacks to go along internal components. Instead we use [Plugins](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extend.html#busplugins). CherryPy's own components like session data expiration or request timeout monitors, daemoniser and PID writer and others are Plugins. Plugin's life cycle is bound to [the message bus](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.process.html#module-cherrypy.process.wspbus). The FSM diagram illustrates the state changes. In your Plugin you just need to handle some of the states that make sense for your task.

```
                 O
                 |
                 V
STOPPING --> STOPPED --> EXITING -> X
   A   A         |
   |    \___     |
   |        \    |
   |         V   V
 STARTED <-- STARTING
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29254591/2072035) has a Plugin example. Also take a look at [Managing your process with the CherryPy’s bus](http://www.defuze.org/archives/198-managing-your-process-with-the-cherrypy-bus.html) by Sylvain Hellegouarch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use cherrypy, you can use [the bus](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/refman/process/wspbus.html) to get notifications on process start/stop. A better way would be to use a supervisor (supervisor or circus) to manage the processes.